# How to include the output from database query in div using GET

Tags: javascript, php, html, postgis, pg-query

i have index.html with the following code

```
<html>
<head><title>Testing</title></head>
<body>
<script>
  var javascriptVariable = "abc";
  window.location.href = "test_selected.php?name=" + javascriptVariable;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and test_selected file containing the code

```
<?php

$host = 'localhost';
$port = '5432';
$database = 'postgis';
$user = 'postgres';
$password = 'postgres';
$reg_name=$_GET['name'];

$connectString = 'host=' . $host . ' port=' . $port . ' dbname=' . $database . 
    ' user=' . $user . ' password=' . $password;


$link = pg_connect ($connectString);
if (!$link)
{
    die('Error: Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());
}
$query="select * from table where name='{$reg_name}'";
$result = pg_query($query);

$i = 0;
echo '<html><body><table border="1"><tr>';
while ($i < pg_num_fields($result))
{
    $fieldName = pg_field_name($result, $i);
    echo '<td>' . $fieldName . '</td>';
    $i = $i + 1;
}
echo '</tr>';
$i = 0;

while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) 
{
    echo '<tr>';
    $count = count($row);
    $y = 0;
    while ($y < $count)
    {
        $c_row = current($row);
        echo '<td>' . $c_row . '</td>';
        next($row);
        $y = $y + 1;
    }
    echo '</tr>';
    $i = $i + 1;
}
pg_free_result($result);

echo '</table></body></html>';
?>
```

The output is displayed in a new page because i have used windows.location. Is it possible to display the output in the same page in a div instead of another new page.

Comment: Look into AJAX https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started

Comment: Yes, you can with help of jQuery load function. Refer http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: @VIJAYABALDHANAPAL Thanx man the problem is solved :D

Answer (score 0):

include jquery in page. and replace

```
window.location.href = "test_selected.php?name=" + javascriptVariable;
```

with

```
 $.ajax({
    type:'GET'
  url: "test_selected.php?name=" + javascriptVariable,
  success: function(result){
        $("#div_id").html(result);
},error:(error){
    console.log(error);
});
```

replace div_id with the id of div you want to load into.